# What's the best database for Electron based inventory system

Tags: database, electron

I'm coding an inventory management system using html,css,js and electron to compile it into a desktop based app.

I want it to work locally on clients computer, without internet connection.

Please share your experience with local database management system, keeping in view electron and inventory management system requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an electron app and you want to use without internet connection I would suggest sqlite. It is simple and it works very well with javascript.

Check this out [Uses for SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html) (Internal or temporary databases)